# Exit from while loop upon hitting enter key

Tags: python

I need to take multiple inputs from user and exit from the loop when the user hits the enter key.

this is what i am trying to do.

```
while True:
    data = input("Enter name age and score:\t").split(",")
    if data==' ':
         break
    else:
         continue
```

Comment: Its working when trying like `if data=='' : `(no space in ' ' )

Comment: With indentation corrected what you have exits the loop with space and enter. Do you need help parsing name age and score out of the input?

Comment: still unable to break out from this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
data = input("Enter name age and score:")
while data.strip() != '':
    data = input("Enter name age and score:")
```

Comment: Enter name age and score: shikha,98,100
Traceback (most recent call last):
Question8.py", line 22, in <module>
    n = input("Enter name age and score::\t")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'shikha' is not defined   . getting this error

Comment: replace n to data

Answer (score 0):

Just check for `bool` value:

```
while True:
    data = input("Enter name age and score:\t")
    if not data:
         break
    else:
         continue
```